# I have to set the phone to silent twice to make it "stick". How can I do it after once set?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, silent-mode

I have a VZW Galaxy Nexus running bugless beast 4.1 and when I hold the power button and select silent mode, the phone immediately switches back to normal mode.  Then if I do it again, it will go into silent mode.

I was using the Shush app and thought that was messing with it so I uninstalled Shush and it still takes two tries to make the phone be silent.

This is relatively new behavior that used to work before.   How can I isolate what is causing this problem?

Comment: Before uninstalling, did you clear the app data? Also, have you restarted your device to insure that nothing from that app is still loaded into memory?

Comment: I did reboot, but did not clear data.   Since it didn't fix it, I reinstalled.   I'll clear data, uninstall and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Don't forget to answer back here if it works :)

Comment: Sadly, that didn't fix it. I still have this weird double choose to mute problem.

Comment: I just started getting this weird behavior too. I swear it only started happening recently without making a change/update of my Bugless Beast ROM. I use Silent Time to silence my phone on a schedule, but it stopped working properly because of this.

Comment: I have the same symptom on stock 4.1 (Nexus 7). As with you, this is a fairly new behavior that started without any OS updates.

Comment: @Aron Mine suddenly started working again.  If anyone has an idea how to debug it or isolate the item causing the issue, I'd still love to hear it and upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: @Alex B - Ditto mine! I haven't noticed the problem for some days now. I can only imagine some app was misbehaving, and they released an update to fix it...

Comment: I have the same problem as documented [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29559/phone-wont-stay-silent-where-to-start-looking-for-source-of-problem#comment41287_29559).

Comment: I'm also experiencing this on stock 4.1.1 (Nexus S). Only started recently and I don't think I've installed any apps that could be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: On my GN also running BB JB 4.1.1 if I want to silence it I will typically hold the volume control down until it gets into vibrate only mode. Then I have to down again to turn that off. So even that is a two step process and it may just be the nature of the Bugless Beast. :)

Comment: I did start using the volume rocker as a work around, but this works on another Bugless Beast install (same version) on an identical phone so it's not only due to Bugless Beast.